# jQuery radio button changing span class

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use jQuery to change a span class depending on radio check ([**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pfg4T/)). I've got as far as removing the class from the first span - but can't get it to add to the next one. I'm pretty sure there's a simple solution - but for the life of me I'm stumped...

Currently using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input:radio').change(function(){
    $('span.StatusBox').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('span.StatusBox').addClass('active');
});
```

});

Thanks

Comment: That's not what [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) is for.

Comment: Will this bit of html be enclosed in another element?

Comment: It can be enclosed in anything it needs to work really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be solved with adding a `data attribute` to the `span`.

**HTML:**

```
<span class="StatusBox yes active" data-value="1">Yes</span>
<span class="StatusBox no" data-value="0">No</span>

YES<input type="radio" name="tickets_active" value="1"checked=""><br>
NO<input type="radio" name="tickets_active" value="0">
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input:radio').change(function(){
        $('span.StatusBox')
             .removeClass('active')
             .filter('[data-value=' + $(this).val() + ']').addClass('active');
    });
});
```

[<kbd>jsFiddle Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/pfg4T/4/)

Comment: Thanks Itay - that works perfect! I've never come across [data-value=' + $(this).val() + '] before, so I wouldn't have known where to start with that. Time to start reading up on it, I think...

Comment: [Here](http://unmatchedstyle.com/news/html5-data-attributes-jquery.php)'s a link to an article about data attributes. They can become really handy. Also, if my answer helped you, please accept it as the correct answer with the "V" button